# SMS DELIVERED listener - get recipient address

Tags: android, sms

I am sending perhaps 100-200 SMS messages
The DELIVERED status comes back in dribs and drabs so
I need to get the recipient address to see which message it refers to.

I see whilst debugging the data I can see it there in

message.mWrappedSMSMessage.recipientAddress.address the value is correct but how can I read this??

```
   registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
           Bundle bundle = arg1.getExtras();        
            if (bundle != null){
                 Object pdu = (Object) bundle.get("pdu");

                    SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdu);
                    String str = message.getServiceCenterAddress();  
                    String str = message.getOriginatingAddress();


                 //---retrieve the SMS message received---  

                       switch (getResultCode())
                           {
                           case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                               sms_log(str+ " SMS delivered");
                               break;
                           case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                               sms_log(str+ " SMS not delivered");
                               break;
                           }
            }
           }
       }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
```

the above code allows access to 
message.getServiceCenterAddress() and message.getOriginatingAddress() but how do I get the message recipient address.

I see whilst debugging the data is there in

message.mWrappedSMSMessage.recipientAddress.address the value is correct but how can I read this??

Steve

Comment: Why are you assiging 2x after eachother a value to `str`?

Comment: The second was added during the post - just to demonstrate the two options - but how do I get the recipient address - is there another way I am missing??

Comment: OK - STUPIDITY WILL OUT!!!! - please ignore this post